# Append elements interleavely with purely javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm gonna append comments into `<ul class="chat" id="comments_section">` with retrieved remote json data

return json data like this :

```
rtndata = [
  {
    username: Jordan,
    message: 123,
  },
  {
    username: Kobe,
    message: 456,
  },    
]
```

## implement ideas :

```
rtndata.forEach(function (comment, index) {
    if index == EvenNumber:
      append_comment_div_with_Even_Number_format;
    else :
    append_comment_div_with_Odd_Number_format;
});
```

Finnaly the DOM structure should look like the following,

The attributes `left` and `right` should be used interleavely in the **comment div template**.

Could we use any template technique in purely js lib?  (Does any one lib of `backbone.js, react.js, underscore.js` can do this job elegantly ?)

Thank you.

## Expected result

```
<ul class="chat" id="comments_section">
            <li class="left.clearfix">
              <span class="pull-left chat-img">
                <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/Jordan/picture">
              </span>
              <span class="pull-left msg">
                123
              </span>
            </li>
            <li class="right.clearfix">
              <span class="pull-right chat-img">
                <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/Kobe/picture">
              </span>
              <span class="pull-right msg">
                456
              </span>
            </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: What if there's more than one even integer in the numbering system you're using? No spoilers, but this may not be a purely rhetorical question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett im not understand your question, I just need to append the comment , left , right, left, right , .... interleavedly.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you're trying to adjust the style of alternate elements by adding css classes via js.

You can handle this without js, using css [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selector:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {

}
li:nth-child(odd) span.msg{

}
li:nth-child(even) {

}
li:nth-child(even) span.msg{

}
```

If you must add classes (maybe you're using bootstrap), you should be able to do something like the following using underscore's `template` method:

```
<ul class="chat" id="comments_section">
  <% _.each(comments, function(comment, i) { %>
    <li class="<%= i%2==0? 'left' : 'right' %> clearfix">
      <span class="pull-<%= i%2==0? 'left' : 'right' %> chat-img">
                <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/Kobe/picture">
              </span>
      <span class="pull-<%= i%2==0? 'left' : 'right' %> msg">
                456
              </span>
    </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
var rtndata = [{
    username: 'Jordan',
    message: 123,
}, {
    username: 'Kobe',
    message: 456,
}, ];

var ul = document.getElementById('comments_section');
rtndata.forEach(function(comment, index) {
    var even = (index % 2 === 0);

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = (even ? 'left.clearfix' : 'right.clearfix');

    var span1 = document.createElement('span');
    span1.className = (even ? 'pull-left' : 'pull-right') + ' chat-img';

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + comment.username + '/picture';

    var span2 = document.createElement('span');
    span2.className = (even ? 'pull-left' : 'pull-right') + ' msg';
    span2.innerHTML = comment.message;


    span1.appendChild(img);
    li.appendChild(span1);
    li.appendChild(span2);

    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

Output:

[image]

Since you don't have that many elements, we can create a few elements and set them.  If you have a lot, a second approach would be to create an html template and do a find replace.